# How to get web server to work?

Tags: wireless, web-server, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi web server set up successfully. My pi gets it's connection through another laptop, but only that laptop can view the server. I want all the computers on the network to view the server, does anyone  know how I can achieve this?

Comment: share your raspberry ifconfig and describe your network topology. furhtermore tell us which webserver you have installed and which distro you are using.

Comment: if your laptop can view the server, it's not a raspberry pi problem. you'd better try serverfault or other network/linux configuration related sections of stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks all, but I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be good to start with the network setup and make sure you've got your pi setup on your LAN exclusive of the laptop.  You can still use your laptop's USB to power the pi if you need to, but you'll probably want to connect the Ethernet directly to your router or another switch to present the web server to your network most effectively.

There are a few tutorials online for how to do this - you might start with something like this from Adafruit: 
http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup.pdf

Also elsewhere on StackExchange, you'll find threads that will help such as this:

[Unable to connect to Raspberry Pi over the network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/unable-to-connect-to-raspberry-pi-over-the-network)

A little googling will fill in any gaps, but that Adafruit doc should cover all of the bases for you.

Good luck!